# How do I sort a column which has a Text Data Format by another a column which has a Text Data Format in a Tabular Project in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, dax, tabular, ssas-tabular

I have two columns "Accounting Period" and "Accounting Period Desc" in my Tabular Model as given below.

[image]

The "Data Format" property of both the above columns are set to "Text".

[image]

I'm trying to sort the "Accounting Period Desc" column by the "Accounting Period" column. But I get an error with the content "Property Value is not valid".

[image]

So can someone tell me how I can do this?